# Linkedin REST API - How to return more job bookmarks / records each call

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get all my job bookmarks (30+) via Linkedin Rest API but it seems that every call only returns the same exact & only 10 records max.

GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/job-bookmarks

then I found the end https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api
It seems that I can pass the parameter - **count**: The maximum number of items you want included in the result set.  So I thought maybe I can just add that at the end of the GET url...

New query GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/job-bookmarks&count=30

then I got an error - 400 Bad Request

Does someone know how to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the query string with a '?' instead of '&'.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/job-bookmarks?count=30

You use '&' to separate query parameters. For example if you wanted to page through all the job book marks you could use the 'start' parameter to do offset paging. So the path to get the next page if you have more than 30 bookmarks would look like this.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/job-bookmarks?count=30&start=31